# He had caught a glimpse of the apparently illimitable (vs. unlimited?) vistas of knowledge

Tags: word-usage

> "He had caught a glimpse of the apparently **illimitable** vistas of knowledge." (Jack London's Martin Eden.)

(Emphasis mine)

Both unlimited (limitless or without bounds; unrestricted) and illimitable (Impervious to limitation, without limit.) appear to be the same. I prefer illimitable simply by connotation (unlimited suggests space and the unknown to me).

Do you think London's choice is simply a matter of illimitable being in use at the time?

Comment: They may appear to be the same, but they're not.

Answer (score 3):

Both words have been recorded (per the *OED*) for hundreds of years (*unlimited* from around 1450; *illimitable* from around 1550).  The Ngram viewer shows that *unlimited* has been by far the more popular, and the google hit rate suggests that this is still true.  Even taking into account the limitations of both tools.

We can't know London's reason for choosing *illimitable*, but the word can have a slightly different connotation from that of *unlimited* (again per the *OED*).  *Unlimited* is a statement of the lack of bounds; *illimitable* means that bounds are not discernible were they to exist. You may consider this to be a distinction without a difference or you may consider it to be consonant with the context of mental abilities.  Alas, this is the centenary of our inability to ask the author for his reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Although the words are synonyms, and I'd say the less rare usage of 'illimitable' is that given by [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/illimitable):

> **illimitable** adj
>
> limitless; boundless [ie without limit / unlimited]

as the [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/illimitable) definition

> **illimitable** adj
>
> incapable of being limited or bounded

shows, a further sense is the impossibility of limits ever being applied or possible.